# JSON RPC Serializing Lists of Objects in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, json-rpc

So first some info about the project; here is a class I created :

```
    public class SendOverview
{
    public string id   { get; set;}

    public string method { get; set;}

    public SendOV Params {get; set;}

}

public class SendOV
{
    public string overviewID { get; set; }

    public string overviewType { get; set; }

    public string AORParams { get; set; }

    public SentDatas arrOptions { get; set; }


}
public class SentDatas
{
    public string columnInfo { get; set; }

    public string orderInfo { get; set; }

}
```

A pretty simple class where I want to serialize the whole thing (So, the SendOverview class) by creating an object as done here :

```
        SendOverview test1 = new SendOverview();
        test1.id = "1";
        test1.method = "getOverviewInfo";

        SendOV testOV = new SendOV();
        testOV.AORParams = null;
        testOV.overviewID = tempDID;
        testOV.overviewType = "Stock Items";


        SentDatas col1 = new SentDatas();
        col1.columnInfo = "1;100;1;1#";
        col1.orderInfo = "1;0;0#";
```

Now once I try to add the col1 data to testOV's arrOptions I get a nullreference exception which blocks my work from any progress.. I have tried much, to no avail.

```
testOV.arrOptions[0] = col1;
```

is giving me the exception; Any help is highly appreciated..

(I know I have to create a List[] xx = new List[MAX] somewhere but I'm not able to implement it.)

COMPLIMENTARY QUESTION :

when sending the json string : 
{\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"getOverviewInfo\",\"Params\":{\"overviewID\":\"0000004297\",\"overviewType\":\"Stock Items\",\"AORParams\":null,\"arrOptions\":{\"columnInfo\":\"1;100;1;1#\",\"orderInfo\":\"1;0;0#\"}}}"

All the named parameters should only have the value, not the named parameter; adjusted :

{\"id\":\"1\",\"method\":\"getOverviewInfo\",\"Params\":{"0000004297\","Stock Items",null,{\"columnInfo\":\"1;100;1;1#\",\"orderInfo\":\"1;0;0#\"}}}"

Which JSON property should I add to get this effect?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand what it is you are after, but take a look at the following and see if I am on the right track.

Update your class like so:

```
public class SendOV
{
    public string overviewID { get; set; }

    public string overviewType { get; set; }

    public string AORParams { get; set; }

    public List<SentDatas> arrOptions { get; set; }
}
```

And then update your creation code to this:

```
SendOverview test1 = new SendOverview();
test1.id = "1";
test1.method = "getOverviewInfo";

SendOV testOV = new SendOV();
testOV.AORParams = null;
testOV.overviewID = tempDID;
testOV.overviewType = "Stock Items";

List<SentDatas> sentDatasList = new List<SentDatas>();

SentDatas col1 = new SentDatas();
col1.columnInfo = "1;100;1;1#";
col1.orderInfo = "1;0;0#";

sentDatasList.Add(col1);

testOV.arrOptions = sentDatasList;
```